# How to add attrib to a renamed file inside a FOR loop in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been scripting in maxscript for a few years as a hobby, only started fiddling with batch files recently (so I'm quite a newbie).

I have 2 questions: I'd like to apply attrib to a file in a loop (going through a list of files) after I renamed the extension. Here is what I have so far (with code I found online to add a progress % in the batch's window title):

```
set n=0
for /r %~d0\$RECYCLE.DATA\$DELETED\[_$G]\ %%f in (*.jpg) do set /a n+=1
echo File count = %n%

rem Fill "bar" variable with 70 characters
set "bar="
for /l %%i in (1,1,70) do set "bar=!bar!|"

rem Fill "space" variable with filler spaces
set "space="
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do set "space=!space!"

rem "Process" the files and show the progress bar in the title
set i=0

for /r %~d0\$RECYCLE.DATA\$DELETED\[_$G]\ %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    set /a i+=1, percent=i*100/n, barLen=70*percent/100
    for %%a in (!barLen!) do title !percent!%% !bar:~0,%%a!%space%
    ren "%%f" "%%~nf.g"
    attrib +s +h "%%~nf.g" REM DOESN'T WORK!!
    echo !i!:  Collapsing $G %%~nxf  
)
```

I've tried a few variations at the line ***"attrib +s +h "%%~nf.g" REM DOESN'T WORK!!"*** with %%f but it gives me an error that it can't find the file (I guess cause it gets renamed). How do we add attrib +h +s to that specific file in the loop that was just renamed?

The second question is how can I apply "attrib +s +h" to only subfolders of a parent folder and itself, but not touch the files inside at all? The batch file lies outside of the parent folder.

What I'm trying to do is rename file extensions inside a directory within subfolders of a parent folder, apply attrib +h +s to each of those renamed files inside their respective subfolders, then once that is done attrib +h +s to just the folders themselves, but not touch the files since they've already been processed. (I want to do the files and folders in 2 separate passes so I can see the progress % in my code above).

Thanks for your help in advance, I really appreciate it!

**EDIT:** I have these settings at the top of my script-->

```
setlocal EnableExtensions
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Comment: simply try `attrib +H +S "%%~nf.g"`

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work, it says file not found:

Comment: `ren "%%f" "%%~nf.g"    
    echo !i!:  renaming $G file: %%~nxf     
    attrib +h +s "%%~nf.g" REM DOESNT WORK!!    
    echo !i!:  attrib +h +s $G file: %%~nxf`

Comment: Do you have this `REM DOESN'T WORK!!` in your code?? note that you can't use in-line remarks; you could try `attrib +s +h "%%~dpnf.g"` to provide the full path; or prefix the `attrib` command with `echo` to see what path is actually used...

Comment: Variable `space` will always remain empty; I guess it should read `set "space=!space! "`...?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made the changes to space =!space!. and the code below offered by Jayapal worked for me: attrib +s +h "%%~pf%%~nf.g"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
attrib +s +h "%%~nf.g"
```

Comment: Tried that, it gives me file not found.

Comment: Try attrib +s +h  "%%~pf%%~nf.g"

Comment: attrib +s +h "%%~pf%%~nf.g works!! Thanks for your help! Now how do I process attrib +h +s to only the subfolders in a 2nd pass (not processing the files at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Test it with these lines included and see what is being renamed to begin with.

```
echo ren "%%f" "%%~nf.g"
echo attrib +s +h "%%~dpnf.g"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, the code above works for me (offered by Jayapal) attrib +s +h "%%~pf%%~nf.g"